# How to get the whole line containing several key words by pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using `pyparsing` to parse the log files. I want to get the whole line which contains the keywords:

- `Input/Output error`
- `Disk full`
- `Quota Exceeded`

My code is below:

```
import pyparsing as pp
line = pp.Combine(pp.Regex(".*") + pp.CaselessLiteral("Input/Output error") ^ \
       pp.CaselessLiteral("Disk full") ^ pp.CaselessLiteral("Quota Exceed") + \ 
       pp.Regex(".*"))
```

In the match result , it just contains the keyword such as `"Disk full"`. It doesn't get the whole line.

Does anyone know how to get the whole line in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching this parse action to `line`:

```
def return_containing_line(s, l, t):
    # use pyparsing line builtin to extract the current line text
    # at location 'l' in input string 's'
    return pp.line(l, s)
line.addParseAction(return_containing_line)
```

Is this parser actually working? I would think that the leading Regex would consume the entire line, since it does not do any lookahead to the following literal expressions. Why not drop the `Regex` terms and just use `searchString`? Or if you use `scanString`, you will get a `(tokens, startloc, endloc)` tuple for each match, and you can just call `pp.line` using the `startloc` and the input string, and you wouldn't even need the parse action.